# Numbers reversed in arabic-english document

Tags: xetex, arabic

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\begin{document}
English: 23.4
\end{document}
```

On my system (XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016) and Bidi v19.6, 2016/05/23), this produces

[image: output: English: 4.23]

Why does simply adding `\setotherlanguage{arabic}` cause this behaviour?

Comment: I tryied with XeTeX and the latest version of miktex and it gave the correct output

Comment: I think this is due to `bidi` package what version is on your system ?

Comment: @SalimBou v19.6, see update

Comment: You need to update `bidi` actual version is `20.6`